# make an array of arrays from for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to put each iteration into an array which is in a main array. 
Like this: `array = [[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]]`

push method and slice, splice

```
var descendants = [A,C,C,D,C,B], 
chunk = 2, 
descendantPairs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < descendants.length; i += chunk) {
descendantPairs = descendantPairs.push(descendants.slice(i, i + chunk));
console.log("descendantPairs: " + descendantPairs});
}
```

Right now I'm able to get the pairs like this but I need to do more logic on ALL the pairs, instead of just the last pair, therefore I need an array which holds all the pairs.

I get this now in console.log:

`descendantPairs: A,C
descendantPairs: C,D
descendantPairs: C,B`

Comment: `descendantPairs = descendantPairs.push(descendants.slice(i, i + chunk));` ???

Comment: @MarkMeyer it needs to keep the order of descendants, to be in pairs, ie array = [ [A,C], [C,D], [D,C]]

Comment: Don't overwrite the whole variable with result of push()

Comment: Why you doesn't using `if (value%2 == 0)` (even)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```js
let descendants = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B'];
let chunk = 2;
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < descendants.length; i += chunk) {
  result.push(descendants.slice(i, i+chunk));
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The push method returns the length of the added element, not the array after pushing the element.

replace  `descendantPairs = descendantPairs.push(descendants.slice(i, i + chunk));`
with

```
descendantPairs.push(descendants.slice(i, i + chunk));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could push each slice to the result array, without assining the new length of the array. The next loop throws an error, because your `descendantPairs` is now a number and not anymore an array, which is needed for using the `push` method.

```js
var descendants = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B'],
    chunk = 2,
    result = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < descendants.length) {
    result.push(descendants.slice(i, i += chunk));
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from what OP did, since she *was* pushing each slice to the result array?

Comment: it does not assign the result of the pushing (the new length of the array) to the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains one issue, you are reassigning `descendantPairs` with returned value of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method which will be the length of the array and it leads to throwing an error on the next iteration(since there is no push method for type `Number`).

To make it work just remove the reassigning part and log the value after the for loop.

```js
var descendants = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B'],
  chunk = 2,
  descendantPairs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < descendants.length; i += chunk) {
  descendantPairs.push(descendants.slice(i, i + chunk));
}

console.log("descendantPairs: ", descendantPairs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop and a `temp` variable and push values on every second index to final output

```js
var arr = [`A`,`C`,`C`,`D`,`C`,`B`]
let op = []
let temp = []

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  temp.push(arr[i])
  if( i % 2 == 1 ){
    op.push(temp)
    temp = []
  }
}
if( temp.length > 0 ){
  op.push(temp)
}

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr = ['A','C','C','D','C','B'];
let chunk = 2;
let pairs = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+= chunk) {
    pairs.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunk));
}
console.log(pairs);
```

Comment: Should really test this. Has serious flaws

Comment: There's a built in code editor that lets you run your code if you click on `<>` when editing answer